# Laravel 5.1: using default Auth middleware globally

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1, middleware

I'm trying to use the out-of-box `Authenticate` middleware globally except on `auth/login` and `auth/logout`, so that I don't need to add it in every single controller. I added it to the global middleware list in `Kernel` (as shown below); however, it gets stuck in an infinite `auth/login` redirect. For any guest, I want the page to be redirected to `auth/login` and stay there.

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $middleware = [
        ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    ];
}
```

It's happening because when it hits `auth/login` the first time, the global `Authenticate` kicks in and redirects to `auth/login` again over and over.

Is it possible to use the default `Authenticate` middleware globally as I've described? Do I need to create a new middleware for it?

Edit: I've concluded that Thomas' approach is good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use a [Route Groups](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-groups). In your `routes.php` file...

```
// Your login/logout routes
Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    // Put all other routes here and the auth middleware will be applied on them all
});
```

Edit: Also, you do not need to add the `Authenticate` middleware to the global middleware stack. Just leave it in the default `$routeMiddleware`.

```
'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
```

Comment: If reroute-grouping is used, don't I have to list individual routes? I'm looking for a minimalist approach to assigning the auth middleware.

Comment: What do you mean? You have to list your routes anyway.. You're adding two lines of code to apply the auth middleware on all but the login/logout routes.

Comment: I mean if my index controller has X number of routes, I would need to list X entries for the grouping, no? I can add the middleware in the controller to take care of this in one line.

Comment: @musicliftsme Still not understanding what you mean. How are you accessing those routes if you aren't listing them in your routes file? Your routes file should already have all the routes listed. Now, you just need to put them inside the route group. That's literally it. 2 lines of code. It should also be easier this way because now you don't need to add a constructor function on any of your controllers. It's handled by the route group.

Comment: Oh my bad! I checked the doc again, and I misunderstood. Yes, your answer works; I thought I had to register the routes and group the middleware separarely again. Part of my original question is still unanswered, though, where I get the infinite redirects.

Comment: You just need to put your login routes outside the group like in the example, and the infinite redirect shouldn't happen because the authenticate middleware is never triggered on those routes.

Comment: Added a code snippet to the question. I'm referring to using a global middleware with the `Kernel` class.

Comment: @musicliftsme I edited my answer. You shouldn't put it in your global middleware stack. Just leave it in your `$routeMiddleware`, and everything should be fine. :)